# Are these yellow spots due to heat?

Tags: houseplants, pest-damage, office-gardening

This is a kohleria plant.

It had gone thorough a 5 day deficit of water back in Feb/Mar. From that day, it started to develop yellow spots along the rim of the leaves. These have remained as the temperature has increased.

Now the temperature could go up to 35 °C. I think it is the heat and the drought it went through.

I want to bring it to my office where the temperature is more suitable to it, but I need to check if there are any bugs causing this before I move it to my office.

*Click on any image for full size*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have not grown *Kohleria*, but I have grown other gesneriads, namely *Gloxinia*, *Streptocarpus*, and *Saintpaulia* (African Violets). These plants all strongly dislike having cold water sprinkled over their leaves. Judging from the character and distribution of the spotting on the plant pictured, I would guess that is the problem.

Watering the plants from the bottom of the pot, never letting the leaves get wet, will resolve the issue. Alternatively, one can water overhead using warm, 85ºF (30ºC), and only watering in the morning.

Comment: Yeah lots of plants are really harmed by water sitting on their leaves in the sun. I haven't noticed that the water temp maters, but you may be right.